# Audio playback with NextJS

Tags: reactjs, html5-audio, next.js13, mediastream, mediarecorder-api

I am fighting to make a web app written using Next.JS work.

At this stage the app allows the user to record his own voice and then play it back.
And then make a new voice recording and play it back one or several times ... an so on.

This is my code:

```
    'use client'
    
    import {useState,useRef,useEffect} from "react";
    
    
    const AudioRecorderPlayer = () => {
      const [permission, setPermission] = useState(false);
      const [recordComplete, setRcdComplete] = useState(false);
      const [stream, setStream] = useState<MediaStream>();
      const [recordingStatus, setRecordingStatus] = useState("inactive");
      const mrRef = useRef<MediaRecorder | null>(null);
      const audioRef = useRef<HTMLAudioElement | null>(null);
      const audioChunksRef = useRef<Blob[]>([]);
      const [audio, setAudio] = useState('');
    
      const dataType = "video/webm";
    
    
        const getMicrophonePermission = async () => {
        if ("MediaRecorder" in window) {
          try {
            const streamData = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                audio: true,
                video: false,
            });
            setPermission(true);
            setStream(streamData);
          } catch (err) {
            alert("err.message");
          }
        } else {
          alert("The MediaRecorder API is not supported in your browser.");
        }
      }; /* End of getMicrophonePermission */
    
    
      const startRecording = async () => {
            URL.revokeObjectURL(audio);
            mrRef.current = null
            audioChunksRef.current = []
        
            setRecordingStatus("recording");
            const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream!, {
                mimeType: dataType,
                audioBitsPerSecond: 16*44100
            });
            mrRef.current = mediaRecorder;
        
            let localAudioChunks = [];//[Blob];
            mediaRecorder.start()
            mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
                if (typeof event.data === "undefined") return;
                if (event.data.size === 0) return;
                localAudioChunks.push(event.data);
                audioChunksRef.current.push(event.data);
            };
        }; /* End of startRecording */
    
    
        const stopRecording = () => {
            setRecordingStatus("inactive");
            if (!mrRef.current) return
            mrRef.current?.stop();
            mrRef.current.onstop = async () => {
                console.log("Here dataType = ",dataType)
                const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunksRef.current, {
                                                                     type: dataType});
                const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
                setAudio(audioUrl);
                setRcdComplete(true);
            };
        }; /* End of stopRecording */
    
    
      const handlePlay = () => {
            if (audioRef.current) {
                console.log('currentTime-handlePlay(1) =',audioRef.current.currentTime)
                audioRef.current.play();
                console.log('currentTime-handlePlay(2) =',audioRef.current.currentTime)
            }
      }; /* End of handlePlay */
    
    
      const handleEnd = () => {
            console.log('Passage +',audioRef.current?'OK':'à vide')
            if (audioRef.current) {
                console.log('currentTime(1) =',audioRef.current.currentTime)
                audioRef.current.currentTime = 0.0;
                console.log('currentTime(2) =',audioRef.current.currentTime)
            }
            console.log('Passage +',audioRef.current?'OK':'à vide')
      }; /* End of handleEnd */
    
    
        return (
        <div>
          <main>
                    {!permission ? (
                        <button onClick={getMicrophonePermission} type="button">
                            Get Microphone
                        </button>
                    ): null}
                    {permission && recordingStatus === "inactive" ? (
              <button onClick={startRecording} type="button">
                Start Recording
                        </button>
                    ) : null}
                    {recordingStatus === "recording" ? (
                <button onClick={stopRecording} type="button">
                            Stop Recording
                        </button>
                    ) : null}
            <audio src={audio}
                        ref={audioRef}
                        id="audio-player"
                        onPlay={handlePlay}
                        onEnded={handleEnd}
                        onEmptied = {(event) => {console.log('--onEmptied--')}}
                        onCanPlayThrough = {(event) => {console.log('--onCanPlayThrough--')}}
                        controls />
          </main>
        </div>
      );
                    
    }; /* End of AudioRecorderPlayer */
    
    export default AudioRecorderPlayer;
```

Eventhough the code above mainly works. At times I have the following problem:

When playing back a recording for the second or more times, the audio play stops to happen as usual (that is as soon as I click the play button) but starts playing only after a delay of almost 20 seconds.

Is there something wrong in the code ?
I do not see any error message.

Comment: No good solution as far as I remember. Only something working in some browser, not all. I did not find a good solution in Firefox. I think it was working in Brave. I don't know why.